# Canvas game not updating score?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have made a snake game and all it good except I want to update a textfield if the score is higher than the previous score when they die, eventually I will make a top 10 list etc.

the code I have is:

```
score2 = document.getElementsByName('updateScore').value;
if(score > score2)
{
document.getElementById('updateScore').innerHTML = score;
 }
```

This gets called in the init method before the score is reset for the net game when they die

you can view game and source here:
http://www.taffatech.com/Snake.html

Comment: What does this have to do with canvas?

Comment: Additionally if you are wanting to persist your score I'd recommend a using an ajax call to push the score to a server side persisting storage location like a database. (a bit outside the scope of the question) Also there is a technical reason for js to be k&r or 1TBS style. All and all I'd recommend you look at a good js resource for style and good practice. (like javascript the good parts) Also Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks T, any good links, its not my strong point, just started learning a while ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getElementById()` instead of `getElementsByName()`. Your textbox has id `updateScore` but no name:

```
<input type="textbox" id="updateScore" width ="20"/>
```

You should use this code instead:

```
score2 = document.getElementById('updateScore').value;
if(score > score2) {
    document.getElementById('updateScore').value = score;
}
```

I've tested it with your game and it works.

Answer (score 1):

A nodelist can be accessed like an array with bracket notation, so getting the first element in the collection (using `[0]`) would be :

```
score2 = document.getElementsByName('updateScore')[0].value;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, there is no element of this name in the source code.